# Eliminate Duplicate Hours

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to calculate the total number of training hours for every user. 
A course can be type=1 and type=2
my problem is the coursehours are being double counted with total of 10 hours. please see my expected result below from more info.

```
SELECT userid, training1.coursehours + training2.coursehours As totalhours
from user left join     
     (select sum(hours) as coursehours, userid
      from usercourses inner join
           courses
           on courses.courseid = usercourses.courseid
      where coursetype=1
      group by userid
     ) training1 left join
     (select sum(hours) as coursehours, userid
      from usercourses inner join
           courses
           on courses.courseid = usercourses.courseid
      where coursetype=2
      group by userid
     ) training2
```

let's say course 123 is 5 hours and is type 1 and 2 which makes it eligible to show up on both left join. The expected results should be:

```
UserID     TotalHours
546           5
```

Additional info. 
Data for UserCourses table:

```
userid   CourseID  
546      123
```

Data for Courses table:

```
courseid  coursetypeid   hours
123          1            5
123          2            5
```

Comment: Please tag the DBMS you're using

Comment: It would help if there was sample data in the tables.

Comment: This SQL code should error?  `form user ` <- should be `from user` ?

Comment: @JesseLi I added sample data

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want conditional aggregation?

```
select uc.user_id,
       sum(case when uc.coursetype = 1 then c.hours end) as hours_1,
       sum(case when uc.coursetype = 2 then c.hours end) as hours_2,
       sum(hours) as total_hours
from usercourses uc inner join
     courses c
     on c.courseid = uc.courseid
group by uc.user_id;
```

You only need to `left join` the `users` table if there are users who many not have any hours.

Comment: if the topicstarter data only has two coursetype types he can optionally optimize it as `select sum(hours) as total_hours, sum(case when uc.coursetype = 1 then uc.hours end) as hours_1,  (sum(hours) - sum(case when uc.coursetype = 1 then uc.hours end)) as hours_2 ...`  assuming the topicstarters RDMS caches aggregated calculation as constants in the optimizer/execution part..